# Proof Complex Numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Let $z$ and $w$ be complex numbers. Proof that 
>   ${\rm Re}\left( \dfrac{w+z}{w-z} \right)= \dfrac{|w|^2-|z|^2}{|w-z|^2}$

I defined my complex numbers as $z=a+bi$ and $w=c+di$.

Now I got that the real part of $\dfrac{w+z}{w-z}=\dfrac{a+c}{a-c}$

Then I used the property $|z|^2=z \cdot z^*$ being $z^*$ the conjugate of $z$. But I did not get something clear. How would do you proceed?

Comment: When you write $w+z/w-z$, do you actually mean that? Or do you mean $(w+z)/(w-z)$?

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{w+z}{w-z}
=\frac{w+z}{w-z}\cdot\frac{w^*-z^*}{w^*-z^*}
=\frac{ww^*+zw^*-wz^*-zz^*}{(w-z)(w-z)^*}
=\frac{|w|^2-|z|^2}{|w-z|^2}+\frac{zw^*-(zw^*)^*}{|w-z|^2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @JoyRocha Please accept the answer.